# In Qt and cmake, how can I moc files generate with my API( dll export) macro

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

In my case, I have a macro for dll export like this:(very very brief version of the declaration)

```
#ifdef EXPORTDLL 
#define MMAPI _declspec(export)
...
```

And my class like this:

```
Class MMAPI myClass: public qobject{
Q_Object()
...
```

Generally, mmapi is assigned as export.

And I take a linker error because of (in my opinion) staticmetaobject which created by auto moc and cmake for not declered as export dll.
I found out some solutions for this. That solutions advice that, include some macro line to cmake file for generate export file. Unfortunately, I don't want to do that. I want use my mmapi.

On short, how can I generate staticmetaobject with my macro.

From now, thank you all for your helps.

**Edit:** when I change library type to static project build but qrc file not found by qml and qt libs

Comment: What liker error? You should not need any additional setup when using AUTOMOC.

Comment: @Osyotr hi, when I add to line Q_Object macro, linker say "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const". Cmake generate moc file but there is nothing about dll export in moc file

Comment: This should work or at least I don't get linker errors when I do the same as long as the code that consumes the dll links to the generated import library and the correct `__declspec( dllimport )` is used when importing.

Comment: When I look Qmetaobject, q core export define as import. What should I do

Comment: The error means that static member was declared, but not defined. The definition should be generated by moc (ie. `moc_MyClass.cpp`). Maybe it's not picked up by your buildsystem? It's hard to tell without more code. Try deleting cmake cache and reconfiguring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what is the problem.  When I define exportdll macro separately and private for each library in cmake, problem solved. My main app lib somehow see the macro.